# Получение информации со странички

Tags: php

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой. Уже 3-ий день не могу ее решить.

Пытаюсь получить информацию  с помощью `file_get_contents` из [данного `URL`](http://angelscity.combats.com/logs.p...59.86496&log2=) и вывести на экран.

В итоге выводится все корректно, но как только к данному `URL` добавляю (%CB%EE%E3+%E1%EE%FF) и пытаюсь так же вывести на экран, выводятся каракули. Уже какие только функции для смены кодировки не пробовал ничего не помогает. Объясните, пожалуйста, кто знает, в чем загвоздка!!

Comment: А если просто дописать "Лог+боя"?

Comment: тоже самое я даже пробовал декодировать сам урл и потом получать из него информацию,но тоже самое! На другом форуме подсказал кто то что информация получаемся с сайта в gzip формате,тока не пойму как может влиять сжатие на кодировку!

Comment: Покажите пример этих "каракуль".

Comment: Подскажите как скриншот залить сюда я покажу каракули!

Comment: на rghost скриншот в крайнем случае.

Comment: http://s004.radikal.ru/i205/1208/37/f19c0fd549b7.jpg ссылка на скриншот

Comment: А сам файл в котором загружаете ссылку в каком формате?

Comment: файлы который в include, тоже нужно в utf-8

Comment: Уже решил проблему спасибо!

Comment: @quaresma89, поделитесь решением с народом. Кому-нибудь может пригодиться.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй это: [urldecode](http://www.php.su/functions/?urldecode).

Comment: Вначале докуменат прописать header("Content-Encoding: gzip",и сам файл я сохранял в кодировке uTf-8 без бум.